Evitar el refresh con un buton en un CMS en webflow
Tengo un problema con webflow, hay un boton que muestra links hacia una collection list funciona bien pero cada vez que tocas el boton para mostrar el siguiente vinculo la pagina se recarga y se va hasta arriba, bajando hasta donde esta la parte de siguiente si aparece la siguiente ventana para dar click.
pero mi pregunta aqui es como hago para evitar que se recargue la pagina o si se recarga esta se quede en la misma posicion del scroll.
No he usado nada de codigo personalizado, sin embargo buscando por todos lados encontre esto:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.pjax/2.0.1/jquery.pjax.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var containerSelector = '#seamless-replace';
  $(document).pjax(
    '.w-pagination-wrapper a',
    containerSelector,
    {
      container: containerSelector, 
      fragment: containerSelector,
      scrollTo: false,
      timeout: 2500,
    }
  );
  // These 3 lines should reinitialize interactions
  $(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
    Webflow.require('ix2').init();
  });
</script

pero no me funciono, vi tutoriales de como usarlo y lo puse donde indican en el custom code en el apartado de home y before  tag y referencie el seamless-replace en el id donde lo ocupo y en varios otros lugares para ver si es eso pero nada de nada
